# Designing Hibernate classes with tables

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate and trying to understand what is the correct way to implement and use it.

```
Creates tables and then use a tool to generate Hibernate classes

or

Build the classes and create the tables
```

Our's is a legacy application, so the tables structure is already there..We are just creating the Hibernate classes and using them...

Can someone let me know which is correct and effecient way?

Comment: Check this [How to Generate Hibernate Pojo Classes from DB Tables](http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-Hibernate-Pojo-Classes-from-DB-Tables)

Comment: When you say "Tables structure is already there" Do you mean that you have the class definition files (for your Beans and Controller) are already there? If yes, then you simply need to configure your persistence, POM, etc. files to support those classes. Otherwise, write your classes and then configure the ones mentioned above.

Comment: what do you mean with build the clases and create classes?
It is create the clases and later the tables?

Comment: my preference would be create data classes and map them to the table and create configuration accordingly. However, reverse engineering as mentioned by @johny is quickest way, but might require extra effort if you encounter any problem in the process or afterward.

Comment: @Johny: The files got creates but its all hbm.xml files for each table..How can I create the annotation classes?..I selected the Type as "Annotations" in configuration properties...

Comment: Thanks all..i was able to generate the corresponding Java objects...

Answer (score 1):

You have automated tools for both sides.
create the classes from a legacy database:

you should use this if you have a runnig database already.netbeans have one of these.

create the tables and relations from entity and embedded clasess:

this way you have to use anotations or a xml file to describe the relations betwen clases and other relational stuff and set table generation strategy to create in the persistence unit the tables will be created automatically usigng the names of the classes for the table and the names of the fields for the columns.

If you already have the database use the tool to generate entity classes

Answer (score 1):

If you use Eclipse then here is a tool to generate POJOs from existing tables:
[step by step auto code generation using eclipse plugin](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/step-by-step-auto-code-generation-for-pojo-domain-java-classes-and-hbm-using-eclipse-hibernate-plugin.html)

If you are using Intellij check out [Intellij Java Persistence API & Hibernate](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/jpa_hibernate.html#link5)